# Playing video on the background of an iOS device

Tags: ios, video, mobile, background, video-player

My goal is to play large audio (some last 20 minutes, some even 1 hour) without the audio sounding distorted on the headphones.

I wonder if it's possible for a video to play being on the background or in sleep mode on an iOS device.

I had some large (as in 100mb each large) .mp3 files, which I could play in the background modifying the Info.plist doing this:

```
<key>UIBackgroundModes</key>
<array>
<string>audio</string>
</array>
```

And also doing this on the ti_app:

```
<iphone>
<backgroundModes>
    <mode>audio</mode>
</backgroundModes>
</iphone>
```

And also adding this on the player.js

```
Ti.Media.audioSessionMode = Ti.Media.AUDIO_SESSION_MODE_PLAYBACK;
```

And it worked for the .mp3 files.

But whenever I plugged in the headphones it sounded distorted. I used the SoundPlayer to play those local files.

I have tried using AudioPlayer to play them locally (trying things I found on forums), but it seems that AudioPlayer ONLY accepts streaming, not local. I thought there must be a workaround that, but I couldn't find one. So I decided to transform the MP3 files, into video files, with a white background. And I am currently playing the video files with a VideoPlayer, with a transparent background color and 1x1 dimensions. So far, it works well as it doesn't sound distorted even with the headphones.

But the problem is that the audio doesn't play in the background anymore. I have searched in forums, and on the Internet, but I haven't found an answer, so I thought I'd ask.

I think it has to do with the MP3 files playing with `AVAudioPlayer` and the VideoPlayer plays with something else that doesn't accept playing on the background.

I'm using Titanium's Appcelerator, which is an API in JavaScript. So I can't code on C, or C++ or something like that. It's just JavaScript.

Comment: Have you tried using `MPMusicPlayerController` with local files?